# Convert JSON to array in MySQL column using Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel-5, casting

I have a column that stores a data in JSON format in MySQL table in form of

```
a:3:{s:2:"12";s:0:"";s:2:"34";s:0:"";s:2:"56";s:10:"1234567890";}
```

But since `$cast` was introduced in Laravel 5, I was planing to reformat my data and code to use with **array** casting.

Didn't find a direct conversion tips, so tried this:

1. Created a column with same attributes (colB) as in the original column (colA).
2. Inserted this in my model `protected $casts = ['colA' => 'json', 'colB' => 'array'];`
3. Executed this code:

---

```
foreach(Model::all() as $item){
   $item->colB = $item->colA;
   $item->save();
}
```

Code executed w/o errors, but nothing happened. colB was empty.
Than I though maybe Laravel doesn't like my JSON formatting, so I change the code to this:

```
foreach(Model::all() as $item){
   $item->colB = unserialize($item->colA);
   $item->save();
}
```

And `protected $casts = ['colB' => 'array'];`

But I got `unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string` error, even though if I `dd($item->colA)` I get a perfect string. And, which is more amazing, if I `dd(unserialize($item->colA))` I get a perfect array.

I though maybe my data is causing this, and tried doing that with a table which had a single row to no avail.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `$fillable` and `$guarded`, make sure colB has been added to `$fillable` so you can update it.

E.g.

```
protected $fillable = [ 'colA', 'colB' ];
```

Could be the reason why your first script didn't change anything in the database...

The other option is to unguard everything in your model...

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Comment: If you look at my code, you will see that I am not updating my rows in bulk, so $fillable has no effect.

Comment: `$fillable` has nothing to do with bulk editing. It's to protect models from mass-assignment. At lease give it a try before ruling it out completely. I don't see anyone else offering up solutions...

Comment: Exactly what I said: bulk and mass are synonyms. I believe you don't even know what mass-assignment is in Laravel, which is the first thing you learn in the framework. One must wonder of your intentions or expertise...